# Content of responsive website goes below fixed header

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have the following simple `HTML` and `CSS` code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navigation {
  width: 80%;
  height: 15%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
 
<nav class="navigation">
<div>
Menu
</div>
</nav>
 
<div class="content">
<p>... </p>
<p>... </p>
<p>... </p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
```

First of all, sorry for the long random content but it is the only way to reproduce my issue on your local computer.

The code above displays a fixed a header and a content of a website. 
You can also find all the code in the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nybk2shj/).

All this works fine so far.

---

The idea of the above code is to be responsive so when I minimize the screen the header and content adjust automatically. In general, this seems to work. 
 
However, for the property `margin-top:10%;` I have the problem that the content goes below the `fixed header` if I minimize the screen size.

Is there a way to make sure that there is always a margin between the header and the content no matter if I access the website from mobile or from the web?

Comment: Please read: [Why is percentage height not working on my div? [duplicate]
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728022/why-is-percentage-height-not-working-on-my-div/31728799#31728799)

Comment: **%-based margins relate to `width`, not `height`.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I further researched the issue and the best approach I could find is to change the `margin-top` property of the content element to `margin-top: 20vh;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navigation {
  width: 80%;
  height: 15%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-left: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
 
<nav class="navigation">
<div>
Menu
</div>
</nav>
 
<div class="content">
<p>Am no an listening depending up believing. Enough around remove to barton agreed regret in or it. Advantage mr estimable be commanded provision. Year well shot deny shew come now had. Shall downs stand marry taken his for out. Do related mr account brandon an up. Wrong for never ready ham these witty him. Our compass see age uncivil matters weather forbade her minutes. Ready how but truth son new under. Breakfast procuring nay end happiness allowance assurance frankness. Met simplicity nor difficulty unreserved who. Entreaties mr conviction dissimilar me astonished estimating cultivated. On no applauded exquisite my additions. Pronounce add boy estimable nay suspected. You sudden nay elinor thirty esteem temper. Quiet leave shy you gay off asked large style. Betrayed cheerful declared end and. Questions we additions is extremely incommode. Next half add call them eat face. Age lived smile six defer bed their few. Had admitting concluded too behaviour him she. Of death to or to being other. Received shutters expenses ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked. Jennings outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed. Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves. On then sake home is am leaf. Of suspicion do departure at extremely he believing. Do know said mind do rent they oh hope of. General enquire picture letters garrets on offices of no on. Say one hearing between excited evening all inhabit thought you. Style begin mr heard by in music tried do. To unreserved projection no introduced invitation. Was justice improve age article between. No projection as up preference reasonably delightful celebrated. Preserved and abilities assurance tolerably breakfast use saw. And painted letters forming far village elderly compact. Her rest west each spot his and you knew. Estate gay wooded depart six far her. Of we be have it lose gate bred. Do separate removing or expenses in. Had covered but evident chapter matters anxious. Received overcame oh sensible so at an. Formed do change merely to county it. Am separate contempt domestic to to oh. On relation my so addition branched. Put hearing cottage she norland letters equally prepare too. Replied exposed savings he no viewing as up. Soon body add him hill. No father living really people estate if. Mistake do produce beloved demesne if am pursuit. Cause dried no solid no an small so still widen. Ten weather evident smiling bed against she examine its. Rendered far opinions two yet moderate sex striking. Sufficient motionless compliment by stimulated assistance at. Convinced resolving extensive agreeable in it on as remainder. Cordially say affection met who propriety him. Are man she towards private weather pleased. In more part he lose need so want rank no. At bringing or he sensible pleasure. Prevent he parlors do waiting be females an message society. Situation admitting promotion at or to perceived be. Mr acuteness we as estimable enjoyment up. An held late as felt know. Learn do allow solid to grave. Middleton suspicion age her attention. Chiefly several bed its wishing. Is so moments on chamber pressed to. Doubtful yet way properly answered humanity its desirous. Minuter believe service arrived civilly add all. Acuteness allowance an at eagerness favourite in extensive exquisite ye. Remain valley who mrs uneasy remove wooded him you. Her questions favourite him concealed. We to wife face took he. The taste begin early old why since dried can first. Prepared as or humoured formerly. Evil mrs true get post. Express village evening prudent my as ye hundred forming. Thoughts she why not directly reserved packages you. Winter an silent favour of am tended mutual. </p>
<p>Am no an listening depending up believing. Enough around remove to barton agreed regret in or it. Advantage mr estimable be commanded provision. Year well shot deny shew come now had. Shall downs stand marry taken his for out. Do related mr account brandon an up. Wrong for never ready ham these witty him. Our compass see age uncivil matters weather forbade her minutes. Ready how but truth son new under. Breakfast procuring nay end happiness allowance assurance frankness. Met simplicity nor difficulty unreserved who. Entreaties mr conviction dissimilar me astonished estimating cultivated. On no applauded exquisite my additions. Pronounce add boy estimable nay suspected. You sudden nay elinor thirty esteem temper. Quiet leave shy you gay off asked large style. Betrayed cheerful declared end and. Questions we additions is extremely incommode. Next half add call them eat face. Age lived smile six defer bed their few. Had admitting concluded too behaviour him she. Of death to or to being other. Received shutters expenses ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked. Jennings outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed. Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves. On then sake home is am leaf. Of suspicion do departure at extremely he believing. Do know said mind do rent they oh hope of. General enquire picture letters garrets on offices of no on. Say one hearing between excited evening all inhabit thought you. Style begin mr heard by in music tried do. To unreserved projection no introduced invitation. Was justice improve age article between. No projection as up preference reasonably delightful celebrated. Preserved and abilities assurance tolerably breakfast use saw. And painted letters forming far village elderly compact. Her rest west each spot his and you knew. Estate gay wooded depart six far her. Of we be have it lose gate bred. Do separate removing or expenses in. Had covered but evident chapter matters anxious. Received overcame oh sensible so at an. Formed do change merely to county it. Am separate contempt domestic to to oh. On relation my so addition branched. Put hearing cottage she norland letters equally prepare too. Replied exposed savings he no viewing as up. Soon body add him hill. No father living really people estate if. Mistake do produce beloved demesne if am pursuit. Cause dried no solid no an small so still widen. Ten weather evident smiling bed against she examine its. Rendered far opinions two yet moderate sex striking. Sufficient motionless compliment by stimulated assistance at. Convinced resolving extensive agreeable in it on as remainder. Cordially say affection met who propriety him. Are man she towards private weather pleased. In more part he lose need so want rank no. At bringing or he sensible pleasure. Prevent he parlors do waiting be females an message society. Situation admitting promotion at or to perceived be. Mr acuteness we as estimable enjoyment up. An held late as felt know. Learn do allow solid to grave. Middleton suspicion age her attention. Chiefly several bed its wishing. Is so moments on chamber pressed to. Doubtful yet way properly answered humanity its desirous. Minuter believe service arrived civilly add all. Acuteness allowance an at eagerness favourite in extensive exquisite ye. Remain valley who mrs uneasy remove wooded him you. Her questions favourite him concealed. We to wife face took he. The taste begin early old why since dried can first. Prepared as or humoured formerly. Evil mrs true get post. Express village evening prudent my as ye hundred forming. Thoughts she why not directly reserved packages you. Winter an silent favour of am tended mutual. </p>
<p>Am no an listening depending up believing. Enough around remove to barton agreed regret in or it. Advantage mr estimable be commanded provision. Year well shot deny shew come now had. Shall downs stand marry taken his for out. Do related mr account brandon an up. Wrong for never ready ham these witty him. Our compass see age uncivil matters weather forbade her minutes. Ready how but truth son new under. Breakfast procuring nay end happiness allowance assurance frankness. Met simplicity nor difficulty unreserved who. Entreaties mr conviction dissimilar me astonished estimating cultivated. On no applauded exquisite my additions. Pronounce add boy estimable nay suspected. You sudden nay elinor thirty esteem temper. Quiet leave shy you gay off asked large style. Betrayed cheerful declared end and. Questions we additions is extremely incommode. Next half add call them eat face. Age lived smile six defer bed their few. Had admitting concluded too behaviour him she. Of death to or to being other. Received shutters expenses ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked. Jennings outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed. Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves. On then sake home is am leaf. Of suspicion do departure at extremely he believing. Do know said mind do rent they oh hope of. General enquire picture letters garrets on offices of no on. Say one hearing between excited evening all inhabit thought you. Style begin mr heard by in music tried do. To unreserved projection no introduced invitation. Was justice improve age article between. No projection as up preference reasonably delightful celebrated. Preserved and abilities assurance tolerably breakfast use saw. And painted letters forming far village elderly compact. Her rest west each spot his and you knew. Estate gay wooded depart six far her. Of we be have it lose gate bred. Do separate removing or expenses in. Had covered but evident chapter matters anxious. Received overcame oh sensible so at an. Formed do change merely to county it. Am separate contempt domestic to to oh. On relation my so addition branched. Put hearing cottage she norland letters equally prepare too. Replied exposed savings he no viewing as up. Soon body add him hill. No father living really people estate if. Mistake do produce beloved demesne if am pursuit. Cause dried no solid no an small so still widen. Ten weather evident smiling bed against she examine its. Rendered far opinions two yet moderate sex striking. Sufficient motionless compliment by stimulated assistance at. Convinced resolving extensive agreeable in it on as remainder. Cordially say affection met who propriety him. Are man she towards private weather pleased. In more part he lose need so want rank no. At bringing or he sensible pleasure. Prevent he parlors do waiting be females an message society. Situation admitting promotion at or to perceived be. Mr acuteness we as estimable enjoyment up. An held late as felt know. Learn do allow solid to grave. Middleton suspicion age her attention. Chiefly several bed its wishing. Is so moments on chamber pressed to. Doubtful yet way properly answered humanity its desirous. Minuter believe service arrived civilly add all. Acuteness allowance an at eagerness favourite in extensive exquisite ye. Remain valley who mrs uneasy remove wooded him you. Her questions favourite him concealed. We to wife face took he. The taste begin early old why since dried can first. Prepared as or humoured formerly. Evil mrs true get post. Express village evening prudent my as ye hundred forming. Thoughts she why not directly reserved packages you. Winter an silent favour of am tended mutual. </p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
```

The solution is explained in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728022/why-is-percentage-height-not-working-on-my-div/31728799#31728799) and the `vh` property is further explained on the website [here](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/).

An updated `jsfiddle` with the solution above can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nybk2shj/3/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, if you move all of the rest of your site content into the `.content` div (as you have done).

Make these changes to your `.content` css

- Replace `margin-top` with `top: 20%`
- Add `position: absolute`
- Add `height: 80%`
- Add `overflow: auto`

This puts all your content into a scrollable container that fills the rest of the height. Which leaves the margin below your menu

But honestly, I wouldn't suggest this from a UX perspective

Comment: What do you think could be the issue from a UX perspective?

Comment: Well besides the issue of using percentages vs pixels as @DisplayFlex mentioned.

Having a fixed header with a margin below it regardless of scroll feels wrong to the user because they're no longer scrolling the page, they're scrolling an inner div within the page. Very very few sites do this, so unless there's a specific use-case I would consider just fixing it the way you had it, where the body content goes behind the menu

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem you're seeing is that you're using percentage values. These values are based on on the parent element. In your case the parent element is the `<body>` tag which defaults to the size of the viewport.

10% height on a 4k screen is very different from 10% on a mobile screen. Consider using different values for your `height` and `margin-top` properties. You can either use `px` values of `em` values

Something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navigation,
.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 80%;
}

.content p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.navigation {
  height: 2em;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 4em;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <div>
      Menu
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Am no an listening depending up believing. Enough around remove to barton agreed regret in or it. Advantage mr estimable be commanded provision. Year well shot deny shew come now had. Shall downs stand marry taken his for out. Do related mr account
      brandon an up. Wrong for never ready ham these witty him. Our compass see age uncivil matters weather forbade her minutes. Ready how but truth son new under. Breakfast procuring nay end happiness allowance assurance frankness. Met simplicity nor
      difficulty unreserved who. Entreaties mr conviction dissimilar me astonished estimating cultivated. On no applauded exquisite my additions. Pronounce add boy estimable nay suspected. You sudden nay elinor thirty esteem temper. Quiet leave shy you
      gay off asked large style. Betrayed cheerful declared end and. Questions we additions is extremely incommode. Next half add call them eat face. Age lived smile six defer bed their few. Had admitting concluded too behaviour him she. Of death to or
      to being other. Received shutters expenses ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked. Jennings
      outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed. Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves. On then sake home is am leaf. Of suspicion do departure at extremely he believing. Do know said mind do rent they oh
      hope of. General enquire picture letters garrets on offices of no on. Say one hearing between excited evening all inhabit thought you. Style begin mr heard by in music tried do. To unreserved projection no introduced invitation. Was justice improve
      age article between. No projection as up preference reasonably delightful celebrated. Preserved and abilities assurance tolerably breakfast use saw. And painted letters forming far village elderly compact. Her rest west each spot his and you knew.
      Estate gay wooded depart six far her. Of we be have it lose gate bred. Do separate removing or expenses in. Had covered but evident chapter matters anxious. Received overcame oh sensible so at an. Formed do change merely to county it. Am separate
      contempt domestic to to oh. On relation my so addition branched. Put hearing cottage she norland letters equally prepare too. Replied exposed savings he no viewing as up. Soon body add him hill. No father living really people estate if. Mistake
      do produce beloved demesne if am pursuit. Cause dried no solid no an small so still widen. Ten weather evident smiling bed against she examine its. Rendered far opinions two yet moderate sex striking. Sufficient motionless compliment by stimulated
      assistance at. Convinced resolving extensive agreeable in it on as remainder. Cordially say affection met who propriety him. Are man she towards private weather pleased. In more part he lose need so want rank no. At bringing or he sensible pleasure.
      Prevent he parlors do waiting be females an message society. Situation admitting promotion at or to perceived be. Mr acuteness we as estimable enjoyment up. An held late as felt know. Learn do allow solid to grave. Middleton suspicion age her attention.
      Chiefly several bed its wishing. Is so moments on chamber pressed to. Doubtful yet way properly answered humanity its desirous. Minuter believe service arrived civilly add all. Acuteness allowance an at eagerness favourite in extensive exquisite
      ye. Remain valley who mrs uneasy remove wooded him you. Her questions favourite him concealed. We to wife face took he. The taste begin early old why since dried can first. Prepared as or humoured formerly. Evil mrs true get post. Express village
      evening prudent my as ye hundred forming. Thoughts she why not directly reserved packages you. Winter an silent favour of am tended mutual. </p>
    <p>Am no an listening depending up believing. Enough around remove to barton agreed regret in or it. Advantage mr estimable be commanded provision. Year well shot deny shew come now had. Shall downs stand marry taken his for out. Do related mr account
      brandon an up. Wrong for never ready ham these witty him. Our compass see age uncivil matters weather forbade her minutes. Ready how but truth son new under. Breakfast procuring nay end happiness allowance assurance frankness. Met simplicity nor
      difficulty unreserved who. Entreaties mr conviction dissimilar me astonished estimating cultivated. On no applauded exquisite my additions. Pronounce add boy estimable nay suspected. You sudden nay elinor thirty esteem temper. Quiet leave shy you
      gay off asked large style. Betrayed cheerful declared end and. Questions we additions is extremely incommode. Next half add call them eat face. Age lived smile six defer bed their few. Had admitting concluded too behaviour him she. Of death to or
      to being other. Received shutters expenses ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked. Jennings
      outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed. Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves. On then sake home is am leaf. Of suspicion do departure at extremely he believing. Do know said mind do rent they oh
      hope of. General enquire picture letters garrets on offices of no on. Say one hearing between excited evening all inhabit thought you. Style begin mr heard by in music tried do. To unreserved projection no introduced invitation. Was justice improve
      age article between. No projection as up preference reasonably delightful celebrated. Preserved and abilities assurance tolerably breakfast use saw. And painted letters forming far village elderly compact. Her rest west each spot his and you knew.
      Estate gay wooded depart six far her. Of we be have it lose gate bred. Do separate removing or expenses in. Had covered but evident chapter matters anxious. Received overcame oh sensible so at an. Formed do change merely to county it. Am separate
      contempt domestic to to oh. On relation my so addition branched. Put hearing cottage she norland letters equally prepare too. Replied exposed savings he no viewing as up. Soon body add him hill. No father living really people estate if. Mistake
      do produce beloved demesne if am pursuit. Cause dried no solid no an small so still widen. Ten weather evident smiling bed against she examine its. Rendered far opinions two yet moderate sex striking. Sufficient motionless compliment by stimulated
      assistance at. Convinced resolving extensive agreeable in it on as remainder. Cordially say affection met who propriety him. Are man she towards private weather pleased. In more part he lose need so want rank no. At bringing or he sensible pleasure.
      Prevent he parlors do waiting be females an message society. Situation admitting promotion at or to perceived be. Mr acuteness we as estimable enjoyment up. An held late as felt know. Learn do allow solid to grave. Middleton suspicion age her attention.
      Chiefly several bed its wishing. Is so moments on chamber pressed to. Doubtful yet way properly answered humanity its desirous. Minuter believe service arrived civilly add all. Acuteness allowance an at eagerness favourite in extensive exquisite
      ye. Remain valley who mrs uneasy remove wooded him you. Her questions favourite him concealed. We to wife face took he. The taste begin early old why since dried can first. Prepared as or humoured formerly. Evil mrs true get post. Express village
      evening prudent my as ye hundred forming. Thoughts she why not directly reserved packages you. Winter an silent favour of am tended mutual. </p>
    <p>Am no an listening depending up believing. Enough around remove to barton agreed regret in or it. Advantage mr estimable be commanded provision. Year well shot deny shew come now had. Shall downs stand marry taken his for out. Do related mr account
      brandon an up. Wrong for never ready ham these witty him. Our compass see age uncivil matters weather forbade her minutes. Ready how but truth son new under. Breakfast procuring nay end happiness allowance assurance frankness. Met simplicity nor
      difficulty unreserved who. Entreaties mr conviction dissimilar me astonished estimating cultivated. On no applauded exquisite my additions. Pronounce add boy estimable nay suspected. You sudden nay elinor thirty esteem temper. Quiet leave shy you
      gay off asked large style. Betrayed cheerful declared end and. Questions we additions is extremely incommode. Next half add call them eat face. Age lived smile six defer bed their few. Had admitting concluded too behaviour him she. Of death to or
      to being other. Received shutters expenses ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked. Jennings
      outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed. Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves. On then sake home is am leaf. Of suspicion do departure at extremely he believing. Do know said mind do rent they oh
      hope of. General enquire picture letters garrets on offices of no on. Say one hearing between excited evening all inhabit thought you. Style begin mr heard by in music tried do. To unreserved projection no introduced invitation. Was justice improve
      age article between. No projection as up preference reasonably delightful celebrated. Preserved and abilities assurance tolerably breakfast use saw. And painted letters forming far village elderly compact. Her rest west each spot his and you knew.
      Estate gay wooded depart six far her. Of we be have it lose gate bred. Do separate removing or expenses in. Had covered but evident chapter matters anxious. Received overcame oh sensible so at an. Formed do change merely to county it. Am separate
      contempt domestic to to oh. On relation my so addition branched. Put hearing cottage she norland letters equally prepare too. Replied exposed savings he no viewing as up. Soon body add him hill. No father living really people estate if. Mistake
      do produce beloved demesne if am pursuit. Cause dried no solid no an small so still widen. Ten weather evident smiling bed against she examine its. Rendered far opinions two yet moderate sex striking. Sufficient motionless compliment by stimulated
      assistance at. Convinced resolving extensive agreeable in it on as remainder. Cordially say affection met who propriety him. Are man she towards private weather pleased. In more part he lose need so want rank no. At bringing or he sensible pleasure.
      Prevent he parlors do waiting be females an message society. Situation admitting promotion at or to perceived be. Mr acuteness we as estimable enjoyment up. An held late as felt know. Learn do allow solid to grave. Middleton suspicion age her attention.
      Chiefly several bed its wishing. Is so moments on chamber pressed to. Doubtful yet way properly answered humanity its desirous. Minuter believe service arrived civilly add all. Acuteness allowance an at eagerness favourite in extensive exquisite
      ye. Remain valley who mrs uneasy remove wooded him you. Her questions favourite him concealed. We to wife face took he. The taste begin early old why since dried can first. Prepared as or humoured formerly. Evil mrs true get post. Express village
      evening prudent my as ye hundred forming. Thoughts she why not directly reserved packages you. Winter an silent favour of am tended mutual. </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: An empty element with height:100% has a height == 0

Comment: %-based margins relate to `width`, not `height`.